# Cannot get response from Java server to C++ client

Tags: java, c++, sockets

My C++ client shown below

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include <TCPSocket.h>
#include <EthInterface.h>
#include "EthernetInterface.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "ESP8266Interface.h"
ESP8266Interface wifi(D1, D0);
void ClearBuffer();
char rbuffer[300];
int rcount;
int main() {
    printf("Main\n\r"); 
    printf("Connecting...\n\r");
    int ret = wifi.connect("ssid","password", NSAPI_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("\r\n*** WiFi Connection error ***\r\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("IP Address is %s\r\n", wifi.get_ip_address());


    //create socket
    TCPSocket sock;
    sock.open(&wifi);
    int ret2 = sock.connect("address", port);//ip of google cloud VM
    if(ret2 != 0)
    {
       printf("*** Socket connection error ***\r\n");
       return -1;
    }

    sock.set_blocking(false);

    //sending to java server
    char sbuffer[] = "Hello from client\r\n\r\n";
    int scount = sock.send(sbuffer, sizeof sbuffer);
    printf("sent %d [%.*s]\r\n", scount, strstr(sbuffer, "\r\n")-sbuffer, sbuffer);


    //recieve from java server
    rcount = sock.recv(rbuffer, sizeof rbuffer);
    printf("recv %d [%.*s]\r\n", rcount, strstr(rbuffer, "\r\n")-rbuffer, rbuffer);
    printf("Done\r\n"); 
   // sock.close();


    wifi.disconnect();
}
```

And the Java server

```
System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress());
BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));


Waiting for client on port 8082...
Hello from client
```

But when i try and send something back to C++ client like this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(server.getOutputStream()));
String s = "Hello from server\0";
out.println(s);
out.flush();
```

C++ client code to receive:

```
rcount = sock.recv(rbuffer, sizeof rbuffer);
printf("recv %d [%.*s]\r\n", rcount, strstr(rbuffer, "\r\n")-rbuffer, rebuffed);
```

My output is:

```
sent 22 [Hello from client]
recv -3001 []
```

Can anybody help me figure out why the string  I send back to the c client is not working?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it C or C++? Because C doesn't have classes so how are you calling `send` and `recv` on sock instances? Actually `recv` shouldn't neither be allowed to return anything aside from a positive `ssize_t`, `0` or `-1`. We need to see more code to help you.

Comment: I am using C++. The code is running on an FRDM K64 that has meeds's OS on it.

Answer (score 0):

strstr(), printf("%s...") etc. operate on NUL-terminated char arrays.  Calling them on arrays that are not securely NUL-terminated is undefined behaviour, eg:

```
rcount = sock.recv(rbuffer, sizeof rbuffer);
printf("recv %d [%.*s]\r\n", rcount, strstr(rbuffer, "\r\n")-rbuffer, rebuffed);
```

try:

```
rcount = sock.recv(rbuffer, (sizeof rbuffer)-1);
if(rcount>0){
  rbuffer[rcount]='\0';
  printf("recv %d [%.*s]\r\n", rcount, strstr(rbuffer, "\r\n")-rbuffer, rebuffer);
  }
  else
  if (rcount=0) (printf("Socket closed")
  else
    printf("Error on socket");  // get perror, errno, getLastError or whatever..
```